# Need help defining a Loop Control Variable (while loops) C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying forever to figure out what loop control variable (LCV) to use for my program to work but I have been unsuccessful.

The information given is as follows:

You will be promoting a student for grades and credits for courses taken. From that, you will calculate a GPA.

- The course name is prompted for, but nothing is done with it.
- We are just using the grades A, B, C, D, and F so you won't have to do so much typing!
- You will need to use the "set precision" command as shown in the book. Set it to "fixed" and "2".
- You will need to use the "cin.ignore()" function as discussed earlier in the course.

Notes

- I used `int total` to count the number of classes.
- Current `while` statement was my last attempt, and it is not correct.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {

   cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
   string course, grade, answer;
   int credits, total = 0;
   float gradePoints = 0, totalCredits = 0;
   float gpa = 0.0;

   while (grade <= "ABC") { 
   cout << "Enter a course name: ";
   getline(cin, course);
   cout << course << endl;

   cout << "Enter number of credits: ";
   cin >> credits;
   cout << credits << endl;

   cout << "Enter your grade (A, B, C, D, F): ";
   cin >> grade;
   cout << grade << endl;

   cout << "Continue ('Yes' or 'No')? ";
   cin >> answer;
   cout << answer << endl;

   if (grade == "A") {
       gradePoints = gradePoints + 4;
   }
   else if (grade == "B") {
       gradePoints == gradePoints + 3; 
   }
   else if (grade == "C") {
       gradePoints = gradePoints + 2;
   }
   else if (grade == "D") {
       gradePoints = gradePoints + 1;
   }
   else if (grade == "F") {
       gradePoints = 0;
   }
   total = total + 1;
   totalCredits = totalCredits + credits;
   }

   gpa = (total * gradePoints)/ totalCredits;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect that `grade <= "ABC"` would do?

Comment: You need a do-while loop here so that you can check if `answer` is "Yes".

Comment: In an old assignment we had to test if a person could access their account when they provided there initials and password. In that assignment the professor never told us what the initials were or what correct password was. In his solution he soliton he used “abc “ and I thought that was one way to check it lexicographically....we have not learned 'do while' loops yet, so i can not use that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way the rest of the program is written, I'd think that you'd want to check against the user's response to the "Continue?" question. Something like this:

```
bool answer = true;
while (answer) {
    // code

    // when ready to exit...
    answer = false;
}
```

That said, it might make more sense to use a do-while loop, where the first block executes before the conditional is checked:

```
do {
  // code
} while (answer != "No");
```

And while you're at it, you might also want to consider using a different flag than having the user type in "Yes" or "No". Something like `y` and `n` is more common and a bit simpler.

Comment: Case-sensitivity with input like this is also kind of a no-no.  I'd probably do `while (stricmp(answer.c_str(), "no"));` myself (because unfortunately directly using std::string to do case-insensitive comparisons is ridiculous)

Comment: @zzxyz True. Just hard to give exhaustive guidance here since there are so many variables.

Comment: @AlexJohnson Thank you for your input and thank you for the edits. This was my first post, I apologize for the poor formatting. I can't do a 'do while loop' because we have not learned it in class yet and I really didnt know how else to do this problem with out all those variable since this is an intro class, all I have been taught is variables, assignments, if and italic_ **bold** `code' while loops.

Comment: @marcus-west No need for apology. If you must use a `while` loop, it's definitely still possible. Just make your conditional (the part inside the parentheses) `true` to start and then set it to `false` when you're ready to exit. I'll update my answer to show what I'm talking about. And feel free to upvote or accept if you find that it answers your question.

Comment: @AlexJohnson So I have seen examples like that, online but once again it's not something we have gone over. This problem has been really taxing because I feel as though we have been given very vague instruction with the about of information we have learned. also, how are you inputting the mini text boxes? I keep trying and failing.

Comment: @marcuswest - You obviously have been taught about variables, since you are using them.  You've been taught a while loop, and if you were taught properly, you understand that a while loop evaluates some sort of expression that ends up either being `true` or `false`.  Basically Alex's first example is as conceptually simple as a while loop is going to get.  You can do `while (answer==true) {` if that feels better.  My point is that I would be beyond shocked if your prof rejected it as something "you haven't learned yet".

Comment: @zzxyz  I understand how they work, my fear is that he is gonna think that I just copied and pasted my answer from some website. He has repeatedly said that he had noticed students doing that. I just did not want to fail the class cause he thought I was cheating. Also, I have to use caps, if my answer does not match the professors, it automatically fails the test.

Comment: @AlexJohnson I finally understood what the both of you meant. I got my code to work. I used 

    while (answer = "Yes")

Answer (score 0):

```
"while (grade <= "ABC")"
```

If the intent is to say only do the loop while grade has a value of A, or B, or C, then:

```
while(grade == "A" || grade == "B" || grade == "C")
```

Comment: That was not my intent, but I did just try to see if that would work. Unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: The string variable "grade" is uninitialized, when the while-loop is reached.